# Trouble in referencing class

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a class named Clientes. I have a function that made a request in AJAX. See below:

```
Clientes.prototype.listar_clientes = function(){

var url = "funcoes_ajax_clientes.php";
var params = "id_funcao=1";
var xmlhttp = chama_funcao_php_ajax( url, params );

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var resposta_ajax = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var elementos_listbox_clientes = manipulacao_strings.separa_dados_string( resposta_ajax );
    var html_div_listbox_elementos = "<select name = \"listbox_elementos\" id = \"listbox_elementos\" multiple>";
    for( var contador = 0; contador < elementos_listbox_clientes.length; contador+=2 ){
        var indice_id = contador;
        var indice_nome = contador + 1;
        var indice_id_cliente = contador/2;
        this.ids_clientes.push( elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_id] );
        elemento_listbox_clientes = elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_nome];
        html_div_listbox_elementos+= "<option>";
        html_div_listbox_elementos+= elemento_listbox_clientes;
        html_div_listbox_elementos+= "</option>";
    }
    html_div_listbox_elementos+= "</select>";
    elementos_javascript.set_html_elemento( "div_listbox_elementos", html_div_listbox_elementos );
}
}

xmlhttp.send(params);    
}
```

In

```
this.ids_clientes.push( elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_id] );
```

I wanted to reference the Clientes class, but the xmlhttp class is being referenced. How do I reference the Clientes class in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Max, there are no classes in JavaScript. If you continue to think JavaScript in terms of other languages you will have a lot of problems. Here are some of the "weird" things (like "this") in the language http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable outside of the callback function to hold the scope.

```
var url = "funcoes_ajax_clientes.php";
var params = "id_funcao=1";
var xmlhttp = chama_funcao_php_ajax( url, params );
var that = this; //<-- create a variable to hold the scope
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var resposta_ajax = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var elementos_listbox_clientes = manipulacao_strings.separa_dados_string( resposta_ajax );
    var html_div_listbox_elementos = "<select name = \"listbox_elementos\" id = \"listbox_elementos\" multiple>";
    for( var contador = 0; contador < elementos_listbox_clientes.length; contador+=2 ){
        var indice_id = contador;
        var indice_nome = contador + 1;
        var indice_id_cliente = contador/2;
        that.ids_clientes.push( elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_id] );
        elemento_listbox_clientes = elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_nome];
        html_div_listbox_elementos+= "<option>";
        html_div_listbox_elementos+= elemento_listbox_clientes;
        html_div_listbox_elementos+= "</option>";
    }
    html_div_listbox_elementos+= "</select>";
    elementos_javascript.set_html_elemento( "div_listbox_elementos", html_div_listbox_elementos );
}
}
```

Comment: I always avoid using that, or even this if I can find a better name for it. The problem is, pretty soon there will be too many thises and thats around, and it will make things confusing.

Comment: or you could use this function onreadystatechange(){
}  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=onreadystatechange.bind(this);

Comment: @user1351310, that is if the browser's JS engine supports bind.

Comment: can be always added like this: Function.prototype.bind = function(bind){
 var self = this;
 return function(){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return self.apply(bind || null, args);
 };
};

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having local scope vars you can do like this:

```
var url = "funcoes_ajax_clientes.php";
var params = "id_funcao=1";
var xmlhttp = chama_funcao_php_ajax( url, params);
function changeCallback(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
  var resposta_ajax = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var elementos_listbox_clientes = manipulacao_strings.separa_dados_string( resposta_ajax );
  var html_div_listbox_elementos = "<select name = \"listbox_elementos\" id = \"listbox_elementos\" multiple>";
for( var contador = 0; contador < elementos_listbox_clientes.length; contador+=2 ){
    var indice_id = contador;
    var indice_nome = contador + 1;
    var indice_id_cliente = contador/2;
    this.ids_clientes.push( elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_id] );
    elemento_listbox_clientes = elementos_listbox_clientes[indice_nome];
    html_div_listbox_elementos+= "<option>";
    html_div_listbox_elementos+= elemento_listbox_clientes;
    html_div_listbox_elementos+= "</option>";
}
html_div_listbox_elementos+= "</select>";
elementos_javascript.set_html_elemento( "div_listbox_elementos", html_div_listbox_elementos );
}
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = changeCallback.bind(this);
```

Generally when you want to call a function within a specific scope you use the bind method.